# Changing dropdown2 on selecting different values in dropdown1

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I want

When user selects Option 1, show dropdown2.
When user selects Option 2, show dropdown3.

After user submits form, Option1/2 and value selected from dropdown2/3 should be available.

What I have tried: I kept the ID same, however then hiding/showing becomes tricky. 
Kept ID different, hiding/showing is easy however form submit submits value of both dropdown2/3.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">    
    function show(id) {  
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {  
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';  
        }  
    }  

    function hide(id) {  
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';  
    }    
</script>

<form  action="showdetails.php" method="post">
  <select class="dropdown1" name="desire">
    <option selected="selected" onclick="show('ID1');hide('id2');">Option 1</option>
    <option onclick="hide('ID1');show('ID2');">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <select id="dropdown2" class="dropdown" name="action">
    <option selected="selected">Value1</option>
    <option>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="dropdown3" class="dropdown" name="action" >
    <option>Room</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" title="Go"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` attribute to make sure that one of your `select`s is not submitted. You definitely want the two to have different `id`s, but if you give them the same `name`, and disable one, only one will be submitted:

```
function show(id) { 
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(id); 
    if (dropdown.style.display == 'none') {  
        dropdown.style.display = '';
        dropdown.removeAttribute('disabled');  
    }  
}  

function hide(id) {  
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(id); 
    dropdown.style.display = 'none'; 
    dropdown.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add same name property to both dropdownlist but assign different id. id is useful for hiding or showing dropdownlist and same name is useful to access value of dropdownlist at server side. you can get value of dropdownlist in formCollection.